# Xamarin.Forms - Best way to open dialog to search file

Tags: android, ios, file, search, xamarin.forms

I created an little application in Xamarin.Forms to get the images in my file with XLabs. It work with android and IOS.

But now, i want to import file and i search the best plugin to do that.
I found this : https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/data/files/browse_files/

But it dosent exist with IOS. And i don't know if it's possible (to search and get file)

And it's why i come here, to get answers.

Can you give me a plugin or a solution to get file/path of any file with OpenDialog, intent, or page custom

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting something that can search files outside of your app's directory on iOS or only files within the app's directory?

If you want the former, iOS severely restricts this kind of thing, unlike Android. So it is not possible to do the same thing on iOS that you can do on Android.

Look at the second paragraph [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_the_file_system/#Overview) and see that the app is sandboxed which means it cannot view files outside of it's own directories.

That being said other apps can make files available to be shared with other applications, see [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_the_file_system/#Sharing_Data_Between_iOS_Apps_and_App_Extensions).

You can also get access to other files from the device's iCloud account. See [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_the_document_picker/#Using_the_Document_Picker_View_Controller) for pre-iOS 8 and [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_the_document_picker/#Discovering_Documents_Outside_of_an_Apps_Container) for post iOS 8.

Comment: Hum, #RestrictionByIOS... I just want to get file and upload it with my App.
With Android it's possible, but, yes, search and upload with IOS is not cool

Comment: I want to find a solution where i can get/import file to make an action on it (like upload etc)

Comment: @Naografix You want to get/import a file that might already be on the device but that is outside of your app?

Comment: Yes. I want to choose a file to upload on my Website with my WebService. With android you can browse file and select it, but with IOS i think i can't browse my note, or my zip file -- my files in general.

Comment: @Naografix You could upload those files on iOS if they were either: saved within your app's folders (`/Library/`, `/Documents/`, etc.) or saved in iCloud by other apps and those apps specifically allow the documents to be accessed by other apps